# Function not being continuous, but being $C^{\infty}$ in Tu's book

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, continuity, manifolds, smooth-functions

In Tu's book on Manifolds, specifically in chapter 2, paragraph 6 "Smooth Maps on a Manifold", I came across the definition of the smooth function at a point $p$ in (a manifold) $M$, which goes like

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$. A function $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be $C^{\infty}$ or smooth at a pont $p$ in $M$ if there is a chart $(U,\phi)$ about $p$ in $M$ such that $f\circ\phi^{-1}$, a function defined on the open subset $\phi(U)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $C^{\infty}$ at $\phi(p)$ . The function $f$ is said to be $C^{\infty}$ on $M$ if it is $C^{\infty}$ at every point of $M$.

Then, in the next page there exists the following paragraph

> In Definition 6.1, $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is not assumed to be continuous. However, if $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ at $p \in M$, then $f \circ \phi^{−1} : \phi (U)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, being a $C^{\infty}$ function at the point $\phi(p)$ in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is continuous at $\phi(p)$. As a composite of continuous functions, $f = ( f \circ \phi^{−1}) \circ\phi$ is continuous at $p$. Since we are interested only in functions that are smooth on an open set, there is no loss of generality in assuming at the outset that $f$ is continuous

My question is the following:

**How can the function $f$ be $C^{\infty}$, but not continuous? Isn't continuity at the very core of the definition of $C^{\infty}$? Can someone elaborate on that last paragraph?**

Comment: Definition 6.1 concerns itself with smoothness at a point. "Continuous" refers to continuity at *every* point, which doesn't need to be true.

Comment: Okay @FShrike, thank you for the comment. So continuity has to do with a neighborhood rather than a single point??

Comment: No? If the function is smooth at a point, it is continuous *at that point*. If it is smooth, i.e. smooth at *every* point, it is continuous, i.e. continuous at *every* point

Comment: Oh okay, I see. But now it is as if smoothness implies continuity. Does that mean that continuity is part of the definition of smoothness @FShrike??

Comment: No, it's not in the definition, but smoothness (at a point) implies continuity (at a point). You can view this as a theorem

Comment: Okay, thank you so much @FShrike!!!

Comment: On a different note, what does Tu mean by $f\circ f^{-1}$? this doesn't make sense as a function unless $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! I have already edited it

Comment: Maybe something like $$q(x)=\begin{cases} 1,\quad x=0,\\ 0, \quad x=-1\vee x=1,\\ \dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\dfrac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)},\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ its discontinuous but its derivative is smooth (if I am not mistaken)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu's whole point is that a function cannot be $C^\infty$ without being continuous, even though continuity is not part of the definition of $C^\infty$.

Comment: Okay, so continuity is not part of the definition of $C^{\infty}$, hence the need to prove that a function can not be $C^{\infty}$, without it being continuous. That sounds okay with me. But if this is the case, can you provide other examples of functions that are discontinuous, but also $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: No there are no such examples. The point is that $C^\infty$ **implies** continuous (at a point).

Comment: @schris38 There is no such thing. Unless you meant, functions which are $C^\infty$ *at a particular point* but discontinuous *in general* - in which case you should tighten up your language

Comment: Okay, okay, I think I see now. So, whenever we have a smooth function, it is implied that it is also continuous. However, this is not part of the definition. And the reasoning why it is implied is the paragraph in Tu's book. Correct?

Comment: That is correct.